# Como convertir de String a Month?

Tags: java, jsp

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario de tarjetas de credito
y el tipo de dato es el mes y la fecha de vencimiento que es de tipo Month, como puedo pasarlo de String a Mounth?

```
String numeroTarjetaStr = request.getParameter("numeroTarjeta");
String cvvStr = request.getParameter("cvv");
String fechaVencimientoStr = request.getParameter("fechaVencimiento");
String bancoNombre = request.getParameter("bancoNombre");

int numeroTarjeta = Integer.parseInt(numeroTarjetaStr);
int cvv = Integer.parseInt(cvvStr);

SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
                
Month fechaVencimiento = formato.parse(fechaVencimientoStr); (me aparece error aqui no se puede)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener un dato de tipo `Month` con la vieja api de fechas:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
Date fechaVencimiento = formato.parse( fechaVencimientoStr );
Month month = Month.of( fechaVencimiento.getMonth() + 1 );
```

Usando el nuevo [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) en combinación con [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) presente desde Java 8:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
Month mes = YearMonth.parse(fechaVencimientoStr, formato).getMonth();
```

---

Asegúrate de encerrar el `parse` en un `try...catch`:

```
Date fechaVencimiento = null;
try {
    fechaVencimiento = formato.parse( fechaVencimientoStr );
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}
```

O bien agregar `throws ParseException` a la firma del método.

Comment: disculpa y como seria en el caso que quisiera que el dato sea tipo DATE

Comment: @programadoraconfe como lo tienes en tu código original usando un `SimpleDateFormat` te da un tipo date: `Date fechaVencimiento = formato.parse(fechaVencimientoStr);`. Tu pregunta decía cómo obtener un dato de tipo `Month`, por ello mi respuesta.

Comment: siento la molestia pero ahora deseo convertir de string a date, y osea ya coloque lo del     SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");
Date fechaVencimiento = formato.parse( fechaVencimientoStr ); Pero ahora me sale un error en el parse, nose como solucionar

Comment: @programadoraconfe en tu comentario tienes "DD/MM/yyyy" y en tu pregunta "MM/yyyy". Asegúrate que el formato de tu string matchee con tu formater, si no explotará. Ten en cuenta que el día del mes se pone con d minúscula no con d mayúscula "dd/MM/yyyy".